# Can't run a wine application from a launcher

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, wine, launcher, directory

I'm on xubuntu 16.04 and I just installed OpenToonz with wine, it runs perfectly fine when I double click on the .exe file. However, I created a launcher for it with the xfce menu editor and it looks like this:

[image]

I have previously installed another wine program (REAPER) and created the launcher just like this and it works fine. However it doesn't really work with OpenToonz, whenever I run it I get the splash screen and it just stays there. I tried running that same opening command on the terminal and this is what I get:

> cristian@cristian-xubuntu:~$ wine
>   "/home/cristian/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/OpenToonz
>   1.1/OpenToonz_1.1.exe" fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 2.3 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
>   fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when
>   filing bug reports on winehq.org.
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x67000000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x230000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x65000000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x180000000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x64000000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x800000)
>   fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0x2030000 0 0x22fca0 4 stub
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x1100000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x63000000)
>   fixme:console:AttachConsole stub ffffffff fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW
>   flags not implemented 0x00000002
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x2360000)
>   fixme:system:SetProcessDPIAware stub! fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW
>   flags not implemented 0x00000002
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x24a0000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x24c0000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x24d0000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x24f0000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x2500000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x66000000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x2550000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x2560000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x2570000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x25d0000)
>   fixme:vcruntime:__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger (0x25e0000)
>   fixme:wgl:X11DRV_wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB unsupported 2008 WGL
>   Attribute fixme:font:get_outline_text_metrics failed to read
>   full_nameW for font L"Tank Junior"! fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags
>   not implemented 0x00000002 fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not
>   implemented 0x00000002 fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not
>   implemented 0x00000002 err:module:import_dll Library glut32.dll (which
>   is needed by L"C:\Program Files\OpenToonz 1.1\srv\tnzcore.dll")
>   not found err:module:import_dll Library tnzcore.dll (which is needed
>   by L"C:\Program Files\OpenToonz 1.1\srv\image.dll") not found
>   err:module:import_dll Library image.dll (which is needed by
>   L"C:\Program Files\OpenToonz 1.1\srv\t32bitsrv.exe") not found
>   err:module:import_dll Library glut32.dll (which is needed by
>   L"C:\Program Files\OpenToonz 1.1\srv\tnzcore.dll") not found
>   err:module:import_dll Library tnzcore.dll (which is needed by
>   L"C:\Program Files\OpenToonz 1.1\srv\t32bitsrv.exe") not found
>   err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for
>   L"C:\Program Files\OpenToonz 1.1\srv\t32bitsrv.exe" failed, status
>   c0000135

Any idea what could be causing this? again, the program runs well when I just double click the .exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was just the fact that I didn't set a working directory, now I just put the directory where the program is located and it works as expected